# Notice : Array to string conversion error when trying to post data from html form

Tags: php

I have a form which allows users to add custom questions which are then inserted into the database. for some reason when clicking the submit button i am getting the error :

`A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice`
`Message: Array to string conversion`

When the user clicks the + button it adds another field with the same name question[]

this allows users to just add as many questions as they want. the data is submitted like this -(when i check the params in firebug)

question[]  […]
0   what is your favorite sweet?
1   you like dogs?
**MY HTML** for the form input

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-10">
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="question" name="question[]" value="" placeholder="Custom Question">

    </div>    </div>
    <div class ="col-2">  
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" 
onclick="education_fields();"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
```

**SERVER CODE TO INSERT THE DATA**

```
$insert1 = [];
$fields = $this->input->post();

foreach ($fields as $k => $v) {


$insert1['label'] = $this->input->post($k, true);

$this->db->insert("applicationquestions", $insert1);
}
```

any ideas what i am doing wrong and the best way to achieve what i need?

Comment: do a print_r for $k and $v inside your foreach and tell us what it displayed

Answer (score 0):

If you use same name with `[]` on html form, then your `$_POST` has an array on that key. So your `$k` variable is an array.

Try

```
foreach ($fields['question'] as $k => $v) {
    $insert1['label'] = $this->input->post($k, true);

    $this->db->insert("applicationquestions", $insert1);
}
```

Comment: Tried and it just put a '0' into the label column in the database, for each question though, just not the actual text from the field

Comment: So your code "$this->input->post()" is getting data from $_POST not as expected